# Dynamic email images that comply with WCAG 2.0

Tags: html, email, wcag2.0

In-order to deliver personalized ads thru email, we refer the `<img>` tag `src` to our servers that return a personalized image ad.

Now that we have to comply to WCAG 2.0 standard, we'll need to dynamically fill the `alt` attribute too.

How can we achieve that or similar result that will comply to WCAG 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your email is sent, there is no way to alter its code, it's like a letter you posted.

While you can change on your sever the image it reffers to, you won't be able to dynamically change the `alt` attribute in the email sent.

I would set it to "personalized ad" to comply with WCAG 2.0